# Determine if a polygon is star-shaped

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I need some hints on this one:

A polygon P is star-shaped if there exists a point p in the interior of P such that any other point (vertex) on the boundary is visible to p.

[image: Star shaped]

Given a polygon P, how can i determine if P is a star shaped polygon?

Time complexity should be o(n) on average.

Ive been sitting on this for a while now, Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: What does it mean for one point to be in the shadow of another?

Comment: @Dialecticus If any point on the boundary is visible to that point p.

Comment: A polygon is "star shaped" if there are any points that are on the inside of infinite line that contains every side.  See https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/halfplane-intersection.html

Comment: @Matt timmeans What exactly do you mean by "if there are any points that are on the inside of infinite line that contains every side"

Comment: For each side of the polygon, calculate the equation of its line and the half-plane for all the points that are on the "inside" side of it.  Then get the intersection of all of those half-planes.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans Very nice. Simple solution yet not so trivial.

Comment: An O(n) algorithm is known, but... good luck ! 

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234830402_An_Optimal_Algorithm_for_Finding_the_Kernel_of_a_Polygon

Comment: Do you mean O(n) or o(n) on average ??

Comment: Every edge of the polygon is an inequality (A line on a plane which limits the plane only by one side of the line). So here you have edges many inequalities which individually cover the polygon. Now you have to calculate intersection of `edgeCount / 2` many (N/2) inequities only (covering all vertices) to find  if there exists a visible region to all vertices of the polygon. If exists than your polygon is star shaped. @MattTimmermans mentions a similar thing but you only need half of the edges (sides)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**very weird definition of star** according to that **circle** and **pie** are also stars ...

First simple and `O(n)` possibility I can think of is to  render visibility map:

1. **compute BBOX of the shape**

   [image: BBOX]
2. **create 2D map of the BBOX and clear it with zero**

   so map 2D array (texture) to the BBOX of some resolution `xs*ys`
3. **for each convex vertex increment visibility map**

   simply by rendering "infinite" triangle/quad onto the map

   [image: visibility map]

   You can use winding rule to chose if vertex is convex or concave by simply checking the sign of z coordinate of the adjacent edges cross product against the winding rule of your shape.
4. **scan the 2D map for cells containing number of convex vertexes**

   all the cells/pixels containing number of convex vertexes are your possible `Z` so if any found your shape is a "star".

This is `O(n*xs*ys)` where `n` is number of (convex) vertexes and `xs*ys` is resolution of the visibility map. Note if your resolution is too low due to inaccuracies you might produce false negatives/positives ... if (max) resolution of the map is constant then the complexity will turn to `O(n)`.

The rendering can be done simply for example with OpenGL and STENCIL buffer which directly has operation to increment STENCIL pixel however that one will limit the `n` to 255 as STENCIL is only 8 bit these days (after changes in OpenGL)... However you can workaround this by seting the BBOX to `1` and clear the exterior of the triangle/quad instead of incrementing its interrior. then the pixels holding `1` are your `Z` this might be used with any rendering engine no need for STENCIL